# Add and replace sum with 3 selects

Tags: javascript, jquery, calculator

I want to build a small ticket calculator with 3 options that add up into one sum live while selecting the dropdowns.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

$package = 0;
    $('#package-selection select').each(function(e) {
        $(this).on('change', function(e) {
            //console.log( this.value );
            //console.log( $(this).find(":selected").text() );

            $package = this.value * parseInt($(this).find(":selected").text());
            console.log($package);
            updateCount();
        });
    });


    $sum = 0;
    function updateCount() {
        $sum = $package;
        $('#sum').attr("value", "€ " + $sum +",-");
    }
    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="package-selection">
    <h3>Choose Package</h3>

    <label for="tickets-Festivalpackage">Festivalpackage € 50,-</label>
    <select class="form-control" name="tickets-Festivalpackage">
        <option value="50">0</option>
        <option value="50">1</option>
        <option value="50">2</option>
        <option value="50">3</option>
        <option value="50">4</option>
        <option value="50">5</option>
    </select><br>
    <label for="tickets-Friday">Friday € 30,-</label>
    <select class="form-control" name="tickets-Friday">
        <option value="30">0</option>
        <option value="30">1</option>
        <option value="30">2</option>
        <option value="30">3</option>
        <option value="30">4</option>
        <option value="30">5</option>
    </select><br>
    <label for="tickets-Saturday">Saturday € 30,-</label>
    <select class="form-control" name="tickets-Saturday">
        <option value="30">0</option>
        <option value="30">1</option>
        <option value="30">2</option>
        <option value="30">3</option>
        <option value="30">4</option>
        <option value="30">5</option>
    </select>
</div>
<br>
<br>
 <input style="background: none; border: none; outline: none;" type="text" readonly="readonly" id="sum" name="sum" value="€ 0,-"/>
```

I don't know what is the best way of adding up the values into the one sum.

e.g. A sample calculation could be: 
2 Tickets "Festivalpackage" (€ 50,-)
3 Tickets "Saturday" (€ 30,-)
Sum: 190,-

*As a sidenote: The dropdowns are build dynamically from a backend and come this way.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, catch the `change` event on every `select-box` with `change()` function. Secondly, use `each()` function to iterate over each `select-box` and if it changed, multiply the value and the price for every `select-box` and add into the `$package` variable. Lastly - update the whole price by calling `updateCount` function.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.form-control').change(function() {
    $package = 0;
    $('.form-control').each(function() {
      $package += $(this).find(":selected").text() * $(this).find(":selected").val();
    });
    updateCount();
  });

  function updateCount() {
    $sum = $package;
    $('#sum').attr("value", "€ " + $sum + ",-");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="package-selection">
  <h3>Choose Package</h3>

  <label for="tickets-Festivalpackage">Festivalpackage € 50,-</label>
  <select class="form-control" name="tickets-Festivalpackage" id='package'>
        <option value="50">0</option>
        <option value="50">1</option>
        <option value="50">2</option>
        <option value="50">3</option>
        <option value="50">4</option>
        <option value="50">5</option>
    </select><br>
  <label for="tickets-Friday">Friday € 30,-</label>
  <select class="form-control" name="tickets-Friday" id='friday'>
        <option value="30">0</option>
        <option value="30">1</option>
        <option value="30">2</option>
        <option value="30">3</option>
        <option value="30">4</option>
        <option value="30">5</option>
    </select><br>
  <label for="tickets-Saturday">Saturday € 30,-</label>
  <select class="form-control" name="tickets-Saturday" id='saturday'>
        <option value="30">0</option>
        <option value="30">1</option>
        <option value="30">2</option>
        <option value="30">3</option>
        <option value="30">4</option>
        <option value="30">5</option>
    </select>
</div>
<br>
<br>
<input style="background: none; border: none; outline: none;" type="text" readonly="readonly" id="sum" name="sum" value="€ 0,-" />
```

Comment: I have a small followup question. Can I create 3 `<input type="hidden">` for the three selections so I can also use them in php to process. Right now I'm only able to query for the `value` but would love to have three hidden-inputs with the actual amount people chose in the configurator per dropdown.

Answer (score 0):

The `.each()` loop needs to be inside the `change` handler, not around it. When you change any of the dropdowns, you want to loop through all of them and add their values to the package total.

BTW, Javascript isn't PHP, you don't need to start variable names with `$`.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#package-selection select').on('change', function(e) {
    var $package = 0;
    $("#package-selection select").each(function() {
      $package += this.value * parseInt($(this).find(":selected").text());
    });
    updateCount($package);
  });

  function updateCount($sum) {
    $('#sum').attr("value", "€ " + $sum + ",-");
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="package-selection">
  <h3>Choose Package</h3>

  <label for="tickets-Festivalpackage">Festivalpackage € 50,-</label>
  <select class="form-control" name="tickets-Festivalpackage">
        <option value="50">0</option>
        <option value="50">1</option>
        <option value="50">2</option>
        <option value="50">3</option>
        <option value="50">4</option>
        <option value="50">5</option>
    </select><br>
  <label for="tickets-Friday">Friday € 30,-</label>
  <select class="form-control" name="tickets-Friday">
        <option value="30">0</option>
        <option value="30">1</option>
        <option value="30">2</option>
        <option value="30">3</option>
        <option value="30">4</option>
        <option value="30">5</option>
    </select><br>
  <label for="tickets-Saturday">Saturday € 30,-</label>
  <select class="form-control" name="tickets-Saturday">
        <option value="30">0</option>
        <option value="30">1</option>
        <option value="30">2</option>
        <option value="30">3</option>
        <option value="30">4</option>
        <option value="30">5</option>
    </select>
</div>
<br>
<br>
<input style="background: none; border: none; outline: none;" type="text" readonly="readonly" id="sum" name="sum" value="€ 0,-" />
```

Comment: @Kinduser Thank, I've fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of adding an event listener to every `select` tag, you can loop through the selected options when a change is applied on any of the selects.

Something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  // Target any <select> tag in given container.
  $('#package-selection select').on('change', function() {
    // Define a starting total of 0
    var total = 0;

    // Loop through all selected options
    $('#package-selection select option:selected').map(function() {
      var quantity = parseInt($(this).text(), 10) || 0;
      var price = this.value;

      // Add calculated price to our total
      total += this.value * quantity;
    });

    // Change the price's value
    $('#sum').attr('value', "€ " + total +",-");
  }); 
});
```

I suppose this could be further optimized, but it should be enough for a starting point. [Running fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kthc4u2L/) if needed.